# How to have a side-channel stream while writing video recording to a file

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, webcam

I'm trying to come up with a way to use ffmpeg to write a webcam recording to a file, while sending some frames to a python process for online processing. The important parts are -

1. The write of the webcam recording is top priority, must keep high fps and not be interrupted / blocked by anything else.
2. The online processing is "best effort" - at every point in time I would like to get the latest frame and process it. Essentially, staying real time by dropping the frames that piled up while I was processing an older frame.

I tried the following

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format mjpeg -i /dev/video5 -c:v libx264 -copyts -crf 0 -preset veryfast /tmp/test.mkv -f rawvideo pipe: | my_process
```

but the problem is that the rawvideo stream blocks the stream that writes to the file when `my_process` does not keep up.

Also tried splitting into two processes -

1. A process that writes the webcam recording

```
ffmpeg -video_size 4096x2160 -pixel_format mjpeg -i /dev/video5 -c:v libx264 -copyts -crf 0 -preset veryfast /tmp/test.mkv
```

2. A process that streams directly from the recording while it's being written

```
tail -c +1 -F /tmp/test.mkv | ffmpeg -i pipe: -f rawvideo pipe: | my_process
```

but again - `my_process` sometimes blocks the decoding and falls behind real time.
Moreover, this approach seems unstable, sometimes yielding the following errors -

> DTS 1626698042933, next:2046000 st:0 invalid dropping
> PTS 1626698042933, next:2046000 invalid dropping st:0

I'm certain there's a much better solution for my problem. Would appreciate suggestions:)

Thank you!
Vova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [fifo](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#fifo-1) muxer for the piped output.

`ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format mjpeg -i /dev/video5 -c:v libx264 -copyts -crf 0 -preset veryfast /tmp/test.mkv -map 0 -f fifo -fifo_format rawvideo -drop_pkts_on_overflow true -attempt_recovery 1 -recovery_wait_time 1 rawvideo pipe: | my_process`

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you! I had to add "-vcodec rawvideo" or I would get an error. Essentially running `ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format mjpeg -i /dev/video5 -c:v libx264 -copyts -crf 0 -preset veryfast /tmp/test.mkv -map 0 -f fifo -vcodec rawvideo -fifo_format rawvideo -drop_pkts_on_overflow true -attempt_recovery 1 -recovery_wait_time 1 rawvideo pipe: | my_process`

Comment: A follow up question: When I try using this solution for capturing 4k video, the fps dramatically drops from 30 fps to 15 fps. Any idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: What was your original cmd for 4k capture?

Comment: `ffmpeg -video_size 4096x2160 -pixel_format mjpeg -i /dev/video5 -c:v libx264 -copyts -crf 0 -preset ultrafast /tmp/test.mkv`

Comment: Increase the fifo queue size and check.

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately. I was able to narrow it down to the `--pix_fmt rgb24` flag that I add to the fifo stream. Is it plausible that the conversion from yuv422 to rgb24 slows down the original stream? One more phenomena that I witnesses - once the fifo fills up, the fps on the original stream rises gradually.

Comment: By the way, trying the same on Mac doesn't work starting from some video_size. When video_size is 1920x1080 the queue gets constantly filled and fulshed, and no frames are written at all. Do you know how to solve this?